# Redux problem Object(...) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux';


function counter(state= {value: 0}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        default: 
        return state
    }
}


const store = createStore(counter)

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>

    </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Just try to run the simplest redux code in your project and not make a Typeerror
 I could try to learn redux and I have the code that works in the code sandbox but in the project I get an error Object (...) is not a function

Answer (score 1):

> Hey dude... convert the `function` into Es6 to avoid `this.` problems
>   and counter which is a reducer should be called in `createStore(counterReducer())`, also in switch statement you need to return a new state that's why.. `return` *state spread in the new object*..
>
> i.e `return {...state}`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux';


const counterReducer = (state= {value: 0}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        default:
        return {
          ...state
        }
    }
}


const store = createStore(counterReducer())

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
    {....}
    </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```